# iscroll5 - scroll event not found in the latest version of iscroll.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll

I am trying the "Drag to refresh" functionality for mobiles using iscroll.js. 
It is working fine with iscroll.js  version 4. However to fix an issue in IE, I had to update the plugin to version 5.

After analyzing for few hours, I found in some of the forums that the "onScrollMove" in version 4 is replaced with "scroll" event in version 5. 
But the iscroll.js (version 5) plugin is not having the scroll event. [iscroll5](http://iscrolljs.com/)

Can somebody help me in "how to use onScrollMove event in iScroll5.js"?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

you should use iscroll-probe.js then you can get "scroll" event

Answer (score 1):

It is given in [this](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/demos/probe/index.html) example.

Use the iscroll-probe.js this way:

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { probeType: 3, mouseWheel: true });
myScroll.on('scroll', updatePosition);
```

And in the `updatePosition` function add the code you want to execute when scrolling.